# What is this small annual with white trumpet-shaped flowers?

Tags: identification, shrubs

Moving into a house with a garden last year, I collected black-pepper-like seeds from a dried out small shrub.

Putting two of them in a seeding pot resulted in having 2 small shrubs with relatively big green leaves and white trumpet flowers. The flowers remind me of various morning glory-kinds I have seen, but none of those had this kind of leaves.

The dimensions are 40-50cm large and 30-40cm high.

*Click the image to enlarge*

[image]
[image]

Comment: what do the flower buds look like? Bell shaped?

Comment: As I wrote in my description, trumpet.

Comment: It looks a lot like [Mirabilis jalapa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirabilis_jalapa) (four o'clock flower). Almost everything fits: leaves, plant size, plant form, flower bud shape, and odd black-pepper-like fruit. But the flower form is wrong. Four o'clocks have petunia like flowers: pointed petals which are often crinkled and notched. The nearly circular outline is not like a four o'clock.

Comment: @EricNitardy you're right, it is Mirabilis jalapa, please make an answer. I uploaded a wrong image of the flower and haven't a right one with me now.  Sorry.

Comment: Maybe a species of Datura: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datura

Comment: Well I'm relieved its Mirabilis, puzzling over it for ages  - that's what the whole plant looked like to me, but the flower shown (now removed) wasn't right.

Comment: As I said @EricNitardy is right. Additionally I realized that I haven't made a photo the flower yet. The flower I saw is not there anymore (heavy rain made it shrink together). I'll have to wait for another one....

Comment: @Korinna, I thought exactly the same.

Comment: @StephaneRolland, it is definitely not Datura.

Comment: @EricNitardy would you mind making an answer of your comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [Four o' clock flower, *Mirabilis jalapa*.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirabilis_jalapa) It is native to tropical South America, and perennializes in frost free areas, grown as an ornamental annual elsewhere. The large, dark, round seeds fit your description "black-pepper-like". See pictures below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

The good thing is you can dig up the roots in autumn and keep them over winter- they look like large black carrots, dry them out and keep safe from frost- plant out in late spring and enjoy or you can collect the seeds every year but be aware that they do cross quite a bit and you won't have the same colours every year. Treat them like dahlia's and they will last years and years- just don't let the frost any where near them- end game if you do...

Comment: Well, now winter is over and I left the roots outside. Soon I will see whether their are dead or not.

Comment: @PatrickB. so are they dead?

Comment: @ashes999 - yes, they came back in some places - not 2013 though.. but last year and this year. Much faster growing and color safe.